# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits) used instead of NVIDIA graphic card or INTEL internal graphic shared card

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, 20.04

I'm using :

ubuntu 20.04, gnome 3.36.4,  NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050 and Intel UHD Graphics 630.

I 've installed Nvidia-driver-435 till about a month ago and now Nvidia-driver-450  but the graphic card that I can see on gnome information GUI is set as **llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)** instead of nvidia graphics o Intelgraphic card.

I 'm not able to adjust screen resolution setting that is fixed is only 3840x2160 (16:9) and I cannot even use Intel UHD Graphics 630.

I 've tried also using noveau drivers  some week ago but also in that case the screen resolution was fixed to 3840x2160 (16:9)

Input:

```
:~$ prime-select query
```

Output:

```
nvidia
```

Also if I want to switch to intel internal card I can see on gnome customizzation info gui is set as llvmpipe

Input:

```
:~$ sudo prime-select intel
```

Output:

```
Info: selecting the intel profile
```

[gnome infos about graphic card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVfAS.png)

Input:

```
:~$ DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
```

Output:

```
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)
```

Input:

```
:~$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
```

Output:

```
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)
```

Input:

```
:~$ glxinfo | grep renderer
```

Output:

```
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)
```

Input:

```
:~$ nvidia-smi
```

Output:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Comment: In my case this happened in a working system after a crash while opening Ubuntu Settings. Doing this `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` & restart fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Googling for a solution I come up with this solution [Ubuntu 20.04 Intel HD 615: No Brightness control or no Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252416/ubuntu-20-04-intel-hd-615-no-brightness-control-or-no-boot)
Considering that I also do not have brightness controll I've investigated in my grub settings, in my /etc/default/grub  configuration.

So I found that I had:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

I've tried to change with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

and then update the GRUB config file with

```
sudo update-grub
```

and now finally I 've got my Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) in the info gnome panel. Now I've also the possibility to switch to NVIDIA card too. The problem of use of llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits) was caused by a wrong setting "nomodeset" in my grub configuration.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! this also helped me to finish the job. check it out https://askubuntu.com/a/1302825/1106093

Comment: didn't work for ubuntu 22.04 with nvidia quadro m2000

Answer (score 0):

I also have both integrated GPU and dedicated GPU.

With `export MESA_D3D12_DEFAULT_ADAPTER_NAME=INTEL` and

`export MESA_D3D12_DEFAULT_ADAPTER_NAME=NVIDIA`,

I can use one of the GPU.