# AMD Ryzen 5800H integrated drivers installation on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, radeon, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

I have an AMD Ryzen 5800H with Radeon graphics, I wish to install the drivers associated with it.

Firstly, I wish to know If my GPU is working properly or not and if the drivers associated with it are there or not. (I have no idea how to do so.)

I went to the official AMD website and found this `Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 20.20 for Ubuntu 20.04`, I extracted this and tried to run the installation script (amdgpu-install and amdgpu-pro-install both) which did not install because it had some errors.

```
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms-firmw
are.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-37-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error 
exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.0.15-1098277); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu (1:19.1.0-1098277) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error 
from a previous failure.
                        Setting up mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277
) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib (20.20-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib32 (20.20-1098277) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have no idea if this is what I should install in the first place.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't need any drivers.

Comment: I read somewhere that drivers are preinstalled, but I have been facing issues that point towards the driver issues. Is there a way to verify if my GPU is working properly or not?

Comment: It is better to ask a question about the issues.

Comment: I did, but I came to the conclusion that drivers were responsible for the problem. Hence why this question.

Comment: The conclusion seems to be wrong. That driver probably won't work with the 5.11 kernel.

Comment: The root issue is that my brightness doesn't change along with the resolution. I was switching between GPUs when I noticed that I can control the brightness with `xrandr` while on the Nvidia GPU. What do you suggest I do here? Or what do you think is causing the issue?

Comment: I suggest asking a new question describing all the details.

Comment: I have, maybe you can help. The link to the question is here. [Click Me.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368075/screen-brightness-issues-on-lenovo-legion-5-pro-2021-ubuntu-20-04/1368098#1368098)