# Monitor scaling issue on ubuntu22.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, 22.04, external-monitor

I have a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro with Ubuntu 22.04  with an external monitor (Lg UltraGear 24GN650). I connected to my laptop and the monitor works but laptop is 4k 2560 x 1600 and my monitor is 1980 x 1080. I need to scale my laptop a bit so that I can see things a bit bigger than they are but as soon as I do that, the monitor gets zoomed in too even though in the settings, it is at 100%.

**Laptop Spec**

```
**Processor** 
    AMD Ryzen™ 7 5800H Processor (8 Cores / 16 Threads, 3.20 GHz, up to 4.40 GHz with Max Boost, 4 MB Cache L2 / 16 MB Cache L3)
```

```
**Display Type**
    40.64cms (16.0) WQXGA (2560x1600) IPS 500nits Anti-glare 165Hz 100% sRGB Dolby Vision HDR 400 Free-Sync G-Sync DC Dimmer
```

```
***Memory*** 
    16 GB SO-DIMM DDR4 3200MHz
```

```
**Graphics** 
    NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 3060 6GB GDDR6
```

```
**Wireless**
    Wi-Fi 6, 802.11ax 2x2 Wi-Fi + Bluetooth® 5.1, M.2 Card
```

**Note that my laptop is in dynamic graphic mode so both my Nvidia and Amd integrated GPUs are working.**

**After changing it to discrete mode**
The issue gets solved if i switch to Discrete mode, i.e NVIDIA but now I can't control my screen brightness.

**`sudo lshw -c video` Output**

```
 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=2560x1600 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1600
       resources: iomemory:fa0-f9f iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:82 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:fa00000000-fbffffffff memory:fc00000000-fc01ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:d1080000-d10fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cezanne
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=2560,1600
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:49 memory:fc10000000-fc1fffffff memory:fc20000000-fc201fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d1500000-d157ffff
```

I had the same issue when I had Ubuntu 20.04 and I couldn't fix it.
[Screen Brightness issue I had with 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368075/screen-brightness-issues-on-lenovo-legion-5-pro-2021-ubuntu-20-04/1400377#1400377) (The solutions didn't work and the monitor didn't work at all). That is why I switched to 22.04.

**Image of the scaling issue**
[image]

While switching between monitors I also notice considerable amount of lag.

Please help me. :)

Comment: could you kindly attach a picture of "the monitor gets zoomed in too even though in the settings, it is at 100%" you've mentioned. Gnome is still glitchy on 22.04, some scaling will give you odd size icons at times. And are your running with x11 or wayland? Lastly, the Display setting is a little different from 20.04 iirc, hence, have you try tweaking each monitor individually while in single display mode?

Comment: I have added the picture.

Comment: have you tried with x11 and using single display mode and adjust the problematic monitor?

Comment: Single monitor works fine but with considerable lag at times, and I do not know what you mean by x11.

Comment: in the Settings scroll down to About and you will see whether you are using X11 or Mayland in Windowing System. If you are using Mayland switch to X11 and monitor whether the lag is less frequent on single monitor mode. If it works better in x11 then test with dual monitor. If it improves while in x11 however, doesn't save setting of single monitor while in dual monitors mode, let me know and i will post the steps to to edit the xorg.conf to save the setting manually.

Comment: It is in X11 already. What should I do now?

Comment: First set your display mode as desired using Settings > Devices > Displays.
Next, open your terminal and cut and paste the line below, hit Enter and reboot. If you see an error message, it's probably the location of monitors.xml, you can find alternatives in the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/is-there-to-make-the-login-screen-appear-on-the-external-display-in-18-04) . `sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config`

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: I am not sure, I tried it again. It just won't work.

Comment: you've tried the different solutions in the link and there wasn't any error messages? And in the "Drag display to match your physical display setup". Did you try dragging, switching 
orders, etc?

Comment: I tried all of them and nothing worked.

Comment: Any solution eventually found? I just updated and ran into the same issue?

Comment: Literally nothing.

Comment: Dear god help this sweet man. We all have his problems

Comment: You understand me baha.

Answer (score 0):

If your refresh rate is less than 60 Hz, the video will be slow and choppy. You may have to change to a resolution/refresh rate combination that allows for a 60 Hz refresh rate. That was the case with my 4K 50" TV. Although 22.04 correctly detected it, the 30 Hz refresh rate made for terrible video streaming and playback.I had to manually set it to 1920 x 1080 (16:9), 60 Hz, 100% scale.