# brightness issue on Legion-5-15IMH05:

Tags: system-installation

I am having issues with my brightness since my first install - I can’t change it, they're stuck on high mode.

Things I have tried so far:

1. Changing grub file
2. Set graphics mode to discrete and saved .conf with settings

Comment: And for the 4th time (maybe more), have you updated UEFI yet?

Comment: @Greenonline yea

Comment: Then you should mark your question as a duplicate of that question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Future reference for any one coming here out of pain and patience, this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1302825/1514014) to [Lenovo Legion 5 15IMH05H brightness control problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1293159/348964) did solve my problem at last, but you need take care of `disabling Secure boot`
and kindly don't touch that `grub file` for god's sake.