# Ubuntu 20.04 Intel HD 620: No Brightness control or no display

Tags: intel-graphics, asus, brightness, nomodeset

I just installed  Ubuntu 20.04 on my ASUS UX431F with intel HD620 graphics

1. No display:
   On every boot (on a live key or on the installed distribution) i have to add nomodeset to the grub othezwise the screen stays black. Besides that, everything start up correctly (i can ear it and run a reboot command)
2. No brightness control:
   The keybord keys don't work and the menu is invisible. When i add to the grub :

   `quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor`

i does display a control bar in the power menu but i doesn't work.

I tried various softwares and commands, I added various instructions to the grub script but there is no solution.

The weird things are :

- I can't get rid of the nomodeset command because the software and driver settings doesn't display any available drivers
- Some solutions online advise to fix Brightness by configuring X11. But I can't find this xorg config file, my computer seems to not have it
- The displayed graphic card isn't my Intel HD : llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)
  [details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfBdF.png)

I hope somebody here has any idea or way to solves this

Comment: Can be a solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252416/ubuntu-20-04-intel-hd-615-no-brightness-control-or-no-boot